# How should I clean up, before I quit my job

Tags: resignation, quitting

Recently I just started a new job and decided to quit soon after realizing it does not fit me. The only thing I concern about is that, while I was working I was talking to people on a website where our target user is populated and asked for interviews for market research. In the beginning recruiting interviewee did not go well, and backed fire because they felt they were mistreated. Thankfully I apologize and got some good interviews in the end. But now that I am leaving, I feel bad because I am suddenly leaving after all the talk I had with those people. I feel that it might damage the companies reputations, especially they know I am new to do the job and hearing suddenly leaving might give a bad impression.

Also, I am the only one in the office so no one can take my place.... if there were any bad impression were left by me for me leaving would that cause any problem on my side? Just to be clear, our service has not launched yet and we are still trying to see if this service is worth investing at all.... and frankly, my boss does not know anything happened so far. He knows I am doing research and got some good interviews but not what happened during the process.

P.S I have not signed contract yet...

Comment: Perhaps is time for my third cup of coffee, but I am having a hard time understanding this. Those interviews you did were with potential users, as in some sort of design thinking way for you webpage? Now, you want to quit that project, and worry that the potential users you interviewed may doubt about the company and the webpage? It is not clear "what happened during the process" that made you want to leave, or that made those users (?) feel mistreated.... please clarify. Also, how come you are already working and haven't signed anything yet?

Comment: *"I feel that it might damage the companies reputations, especially they know I am new to do the job and hearing suddenly leaving might give a bad impression."* - Also,  How will these users know you quit? Unless they work with you/your current company I doubt they will ever find out

Comment: The interview has nothing to do with my I want to quit my job, originally I was told that I will be working as a designer for the company. However now I was told that is not important and I should be forcuing on IT task like maintance for website and stuff.... as well as I am only one in the office and no one is working with me at all...I felt is not for me....

Comment: Long story but…the first contract he given me was a draft and ask me to sign…and even the date was set in 2012 so I asked for a re-contract and the second one was written everything in American law….and I am not even in US…and I am still waiting for third one also because they want me to do IT work…which I deiced I want to quit by than

Comment: yes, you are right! I am conducting an interview for potential users, and had trouble finding them… so I found a forum where one set of potential user uses and asked them for interview there.  When I approached them they felt they were mis treated and later I re-explained to them so they did not felt that way. But thankfully there were some people help me with some interviews. Is just that some people are still contacting me for help but also some people still view the company in a negative ways because how I approach them.

Comment: And if my boss see it not sure how he will react..to be honest my boss never really explained to me, what does the company do until my interviewees  and found out it was differnent than what I told them...that is why they felt lied to...

Comment: Heh .. you're from Le15 ?

Comment: What is that???....I dont think so?

Comment: @PinkCoffe I'm starting to think that the fault of not understanding the job might be on your side, seeing how you struggle to form grammatically correct sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I clean up, before I quit my job

You don't have a job to quit. So you don't need to do anything.

Even if you did, it's not your responsibility to work this out. During your notice period you should be given direction on what you need to complete. In your case you don't have anything to complete, so at most probably no more than passing contact details and transcripts if any.

> some people still view the company in a negative ways because how I approach them.

This is the companies problem not yours, it highlights the haphazard way they went about everything. You were unsuitable for the position yet they gave you the job. Then they did not even monitor your work or progress. Your best option is to quietly disassociate yourself from this brief employment (if you even call it that).

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes you are right! I should just enjoy my cup of tea! Thanks you